# Количество строк и столбцов с данными EPPlus

Tags: c#, visual-studio, excel

Для работы с Excel использую библиотеку EPPlus. Как с ее помощью получить количество строк и столбцов на листе, в которых есть данные?

Answer (score -1):

```
var _ws = _xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("SalesReport");
var _table = _ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(_orders, true);
int iRows = _table.Rows;
int iColumns = _table.Columhs;
--
var _ws = _xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
int iRows = _ws.Dimension.Rows;
int iColumns = _ws.Dimension.Columns;
```

Comment: Можете дописать почему Вы считаете что этот код является ответом на вопрос? И что такое `_orders` и `SalesReport` тоже напишите.